# Best practice create a C# Object which reflect and generate a Serialized string

Tags: c#, coding-style

This question may be asked or answered before but I feel that none of the hits really apply.

I would like to create a little class with attributes which will correspond to name and attributes in a output familiar to xml stream. The class should help the program to create a xml-alike string.

```
string test = "<graph caption='SomeHeader' attribute9='#someotherinfo'>" +
                 "<set name='2004' value='37800' color='AFD8F8' />" +
                 "<set name='2005' value='21900' color='F6BD0F' />" +
                 "<set name='2006' value='32900' color='8BBA00' />" +
                  "<set name='2007' value='39800' color='FF8E46' />" +
              "</graph>";
```

I think you got the idea. I have a static amount of known attributes which will be used in the tags. The only Tags here is **set** and **graph**.

I would like to do something like this,

```
Helper o = new Helper()
List<Tag> tag = new List<Tag>();
foreach (var someitem in somedatabaseresult)
{
   tag.Add(New Graph() { Caption = someitem.field , attribute9 = someitem.otherField });
   foreach (var detail in someitem)
   {
     tag.Add(new Set() { name = detail.Year, value = detail.Value color = detail.Color });
   }
}
o.Generate(); // Which will create the structure of result sample above

// and for future extension.. 
// o.GenerateXml();
// o.GenerateJson();
```

Please remember that this code is pesudo, just taken from my head. A result of that I have some ideas but it take a day to code and test what best (or whorse).

What would be best practice to solve this task?

[EDIT]
This mysterious "Helper" is the (unluckily typed) class who contains a list of Graph, a list of Set and also (what I think about) contains all available attributes per Graph/Set object. The work of the foreach-loops above are mentioned to fill the Helper class with the data.

[EDIT2]
Result here,
https://gist.github.com/1233331

Comment: I like your mysterious `Helper` object.

Comment: @ChaosPandion, thank's. The question still applies, though ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just create a couple of classes: Graph and Set.  Graph would have a property of `List<Set>`.

In your `foreach` you can then create an instance or Graph and add instances of Set to its list.

When you're done use the XML Serializer to serialize the Graph object out to XML.  Nice and easy to then output to another format as well if your needs change later e.g. serialize to JSON.

Edit following comment:

From top my head so may not be 100% correct...

```
var myGraph = BuildMeAGraph();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Graph));
var writer = XmlWriter.Create("myfile.xml");
serializer.Serialize(writer, myGraph);
```

But something like that should write it out to a file.  If you want the XML in memory then write it out to an XMLTextWriter based on a memory stream instead and then you can write the contents to a string variable or do whatever you need with it.

Comment: You may be nearest to where I'm already are. Though I think i'm to uncommon at the XmlSerialiser in this scenario. Not much like MemoryStream here..:). You think this is a nice way to go?

Comment: I'm using this approach successfully on a few projects - in my case the object graph can be returned in a few formats hence it's nice and easy to build a simple object graph of the data and then pass it to the appropriate serializer to actually process it.  Your mysterious Helper can be the thing that take a graph and then manages serializing it using the appropriate style depending on what format the calling code asks for.

Comment: I edited my question a little. It appears that I'm on right track, still yet find out how to find goal. Would you mind describe a  XmlSerializer-process in this .GenerateXml() method?

Comment: With your approach and two hours of work, I will say, resulted in a nice generic solution. https://gist.github.com/1233331 which contain object, textversion and a valid xml-output.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an XML, out of the object tree, then I think, you could try this:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument
(
   somedatabaseresult.Select
   ( someitem =>
     new XElement("graph", 
                  new XAttribute("Caption", ""),
                  new XAttribute("attribute9", "#something"),
                  someitem.Select
                  (detail =>
                      new XElement("Set", 
                                   new XAttribute("name", "2003"),            
                                   new XAttribute("value", "34784"),
                                   new XAttribute("color", "#003300")
                  )    

   )

);

//save to file as XML
doc.Save("output.xml");

//save to local variable as XML string
string test = doc.ToString();
```

I wrote the save value for tags, as you've used in your code. However, I think you would like this:

```
new XAttribute("name", detail.name),            
new XAttribute("value", detail.value),
new XAttribute("color", detail.color)
```

Or whatever value you want to give to each attribute from  the object `detail`.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: I think `XDocument` is more elegant than `XmlDocument` if you use .Net 3.5 or above.

Comment: This is a kind of way to create such xml. The point i'm looking for is to make the object hardly typed. There are a third party tool which require this output format. I feel it's ugly just concatenate and stringify, until the whole string "look just okey".

Comment: @Jonas: What do you mean by `the object hardly typed`? If you in memory XML string, then you can do : `string xml = doc.ToString()`.

Comment: @Chaos, I mean those names as string `new XElement("Set", "..."), new XAttribute("name", "2003"),` (**Set** And **Name**). But I starting to see a nice way to use this. Adding one XElement per each **Graph** element, inside each Graph - Add  Attributes. Then add each **Set** element.

Comment: @Jonas: You're unable to describe what exactly you want.

Comment: @Nawas, Probably. I'm afraid I can describe better, after I find a nice way to solve it. Spoken languages can also be a kind of limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the ExpandoObject, but I don't see the reason for what you are doing.