# Dataset XML question

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net

In `VB.NET` when I use the WriteXML of DataSet, can I customize it?
That is to say;

I want to make a structure like this:

```
<products>
<product id="" title="">
<product id="" title="">
<product id="" title="">
</products>
```

How can I do? Thanks..

Comment: You can get a hint from my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502106/string-output-from-a-c-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`DataSet.GetXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.getxml.aspx) Method and [`ColumnMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnmapping.aspx) accordingly

```
Dim column As DataColumn
For Each column In ds.Tables.Item(0).Columns
    column.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute
Next
Dim xml As String = ds.GetXml()
```

Comment: That's the ticket, been using it for years.

Comment: Thank you DSW but can I give the different name to xml attributes for example while column name customerID , can I give "cust" ?